# Return value when form button clicked using AJAX request to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

If I click on the submit button, system will display option and button value. Below is my coding, please help. I'm trying using so many methods but still have a problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Person1</option>
<option value="2">Person2</option>
<option value="3">Person3</option>
<option value="4">Person4</option>
</select>
<input name="usersa" type="button" onClick="showUser(this.value)" value="button">
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

getuser.php as below. This will return the value to above coding

```
    <?php
$q = $_GET['users'];
echo "test:" .$q;
?>
```

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: In your script, you are sending a parameter `q` but in your PHP you are trying to read `users`

Comment: so either send the selected user value to the php file `xmlhttp.open("POST","getuser.php?q="+str+'&users='+document.forms[0].users.value,true);`

Comment: hi. i still facing a error for coding above. please assist